# Does the story of Madhavrao Peshva contradict the Gita

Tags: happiness, hinduism, duty

I would like to hear ideas on whether the story of Madhavrao Peshva (a brahmin-born who performed the duty of a warrior) **contradicts** the Gita's teaching that one should perform their own duty (and never another's)?

I theoreticise that it isn't based on Tilak's point of view. This is due to Madhavrao Peshva performing duty necessary of his time?

Comment: Hi Michelle and welcome. I wouldn't call this "off-topic" here, but you'll probably get more of a response at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/. There are relatively few experts in Hindu religious philosophy active here.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica

Comment: This seems to be a perfectly legitimate philosophical question outside of the philosophical question.  Swami Vishwananda, if anyone who contributes regularly, would be able to provide an answer.